# Subgroup problem

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G=\langle A \rangle \leq S_n$ and $H\leq \langle B \rangle$.

Can somebody help me to prove the following.

If for each $b\in B $ is a member of $G$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $b \in B$? Otherwise it is (even more) trivial right?

Comment: Yes you are right. $b \in B$ I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for each $b \in \langle B \rangle$ we have $b \in G$, then

$$H \subseteq \langle B \rangle \subseteq G$$

Finally, $H$ is a group in its own right, so $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Even if we only assume that $b \in B$ implies $b \in G$, we have

$$B \subseteq G \implies \langle B \rangle \subseteq G$$

since $G$ is a group, and so is closed under multiplication (and inversion).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\langle B \rangle$ is the smallest group containing $B$. Hence, if $b \in G$ for all $b \in B$, then $\langle B \rangle < G$. Thus, $H < G$.